# Deleting workbook variable in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I've assigned a workbook to variable.
Then I'm doying some stuff and saving the file and closing the workbook:

Is setting workbook to Nothing a good idea if i want to use this code in a loop?

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(a_ven_lst1)
        Set wb_input1 = Application.Workbooks.Add
        Set ws_input1 = wb_input1.Sheets(1)
        .Rows(1).Copy ws_input1.Rows(1)
        .Rows(d_fst_ven_row & ":" & d_lst_ven_row).Copy ws_input1.Rows(2)
        s_save_path = f_str_file_name(ws_input1.Cells(2, i_ven_col_cnt).Value)
        s_file_path = s_path & "\" & s_save_path & ".xlsx"
        a_ven_lst1(i, 2) = s_file_path
        wb_input1.SaveAs Filename:=s_file_path
        wb_input1.Close True
        Set wb_input1 = Nothing
    Next i
```

Am I killing this variable in a proper way?
I saw some objects still existing in VBA editor after crushing the code but far beyond this point.

Comment: IMO, the best approach is to `Dim` the variable to the smallest scope it is needed for. In this case, I'd declare `wb_input1` inside the loop. You wouldn't then have to unset it.

Comment: Since you're reusing it in the loop you don't actually need to set it to nothing within the loop. Realistically as long as it is scoped local to the sub then it will be cleaned up by default.

Comment: @A.S.H the smallest scope in VBA is procedure level; a loop doesn't have its own scope. I'd extract the loop body into its own procedure and declare the variable *there*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug you're right, excellent suggestions. I always scope the deepest possible like I do in C++, but forgot that it doesnt make difference in VBA :)

Comment: @A.S.H IMO it's good practice still - you're declaring things close to where they're used, as opposed to somewhere in a wall of declarations at the top of a procedure; mucho kudos!

Comment: @Mat'sMug, that is reminding me something...

Comment: @Mat'sMug Exactly, one can still apply this rule as a sort of "self discipline" in VBA. Thanks for reminding me this. :)

Comment: @Eswemenasja, is the code you showed wrapped in an outer `With -End With` block?

Comment: @user3598756 Yes it is wrapped in with that relates to workbook ws_input from which the rows are copied. Maybe killing files by path is the issue?

Comment: If there's a `With` block there, the code you've posted shows that it's useless/redundant (nothing in this code seems to use it).

Comment: @user3598756 gah, I'm blind lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternative code not to worry about workbook variable setting and unsetting

```
With ws_input

    '...

    Dim rowToCopy1 As Range, rowToCopy2 As Range        
    Set rowToCopy1 = .Rows(1) '<--| set first row to copy, since it's "constant" against the subsequent loop
    Set rowToCopy2 = .Rows(d_fst_ven_row & ":" & d_lst_ven_row) '<--| set second row to copy, since it's "constant" against the subsequent loop

    For i = 1 To UBound(a_ven_lst1)
        With Application.Workbooks.Add '<--| open a new workbook and reference its instance
            With .Sheets(1) '<--| reference referenced workbook sheet(1)
                rowToCopy1.Copy .Rows(1)
                rowToCopy1.Copy .Rows(2)
                s_save_path = f_str_file_name(.Cells(2, i_ven_col_cnt).Value)
            End With
            s_file_path = s_path & "\" & s_save_path & ".xlsx"
            a_ven_lst1(i, 2) = s_file_path
            .SaveAs Filename:=s_file_path
            .Close True
        End With '<--| discard the instance of the opened workbok
    Next i

    '...

End With
```

Comment: Neat! How I wish every single `With` block in the world owned and held the object reference... sad that `With` blocks are, too often, only used to reduce the number of keystrokes needed to write the code.

Comment: Good idea, an indirect way to achieve the scoping ;)

Comment: @Eswemenasja, if my answer solved your question you may want to mark it as accepted. thank you!

Comment: @user3598756 It is a very nice solution. So you say that in VBA the 'With' is a scope like sub of fun, and it resets the variable on 'End With'? Will it reset all variables used or just those that were opened by it in one row? Please accept upvote till I'll have it tested.

Comment: if the `object` has never been instantiated before the `With object` statement then it gets instantiated there and released at `End With`. While if the `object` has already been instantiated before `With object` then it gets released at any `Set object = Nothing` or at reaching its end of scope

Comment: @user3598756 Haven't tested it yet, but going to use it. Very nice slack o knowledge.